# make a final authentication middleware to return data and validate user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, mongoose

hello there I'm trying to implement a method to handle returning data in my express project, I want to pass data in all my controllers to a final middleware which its job is to check whether the user has the authority to operate on the document and then return the data ,

```
    req.document = order;
    req.validateFields = [
    order.senderId._id.toString(),
    order.recieverId._id.toString(),
    order.driverId._id.toString(),
  ];
  next();
```

then I handle it in my final middleware like this

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const document = req.document;
  if (!req.validateFields.includes(req.user._id.toString()))
  console.log("not authorized");
  await document.save();
  res.status(200).json({
    document,
  });
});
```

first of all is this a bad practice ? since I save my document after passing the user validations so the data manipulations that have been done in the controllers will not be saved if the user was not authenticated , and then how to handle the other document methods like findByIdandDelete, findByIdAndUpdate which will save the document right away?

thanks.